# Передача функции как аргумента другой функции без использования указателя

Tags: callback, c, указатели, функции

В языке Си можно передать функцию в качестве аргумента другой функции, используя указатель на функцию. Мне попалось вот такое:

```
double dydx(double f(double), double x, double eps)
{
  return (f(x + eps * 0.5) + f(x – eps * 0.5)) / eps;
}

double power2(double x)
{
  return x * x + 2;
}

void main()
{
  printf("%lf", dydx(power2, 2.0, 1E-5));
}
```

Всё то же самое, что при использовании указателя на функцию, только без указателя. Программа работает (Borland C++ Builder 6). Но как? Там такой же механизм, как при использовании указателей или что-нибудь другое?

По определённым причинам мне нужно знать именно то, как это работает.

Comment: Именно так. Имя функции это и есть указатель на ее точку входа.

Comment: http://it.kgsu.ru/C_RAZN/razn0004.html - ссылка на функцию.
Что удивило-то??

Comment: @smackmychi, т.е. имя функции может быть как указателем на тело функции, так и ссылкой?

Comment: @smackmychi, ссылки же с амперсандами объявляются. Прототип функции со ссылкой я бы ожидал увидеть так:

  double dydx(double (&f)(double), double x, double eps);

Тогда всё остальное не вызывало бы вопросов.

Comment: @Modus, ссылка (с амперсандом) это понятие C++, а не C. 

--

Наверное, можно сказать, что в Си указатель и ссылка это по большей части синонимы (по крайней мере на уровне неформального программистского общения).

Только всегда надо держать в голове, что, помимо реальных указателей, (занимающих память), есть, скажем так, виртуальные (имена массивов и функций). В правой части выражения они ведут себя (синтаксически) так же, как и обычный указатель (например `char *p;`), но вот присвоить им новое значение нельзя.

Если угодно, то это и есть ссылки в Си.

Comment: Ну, корректнее было бы сказать, что в Си вообще нет такой конструкции, как ссылки в C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Фактически там используется указатель. Просто Вы обошлись без предварительного typedef, объявив, что Вы хотите получить, прямо в перечне параметров. Не уверен, что так, должно быть, можно, согласно стандарту, это надо смотреть, но если какие-то компиляторы это поддерживают - почему бы нет?